# Split all lines columns by different number of spaces, tabs

Tags: regex, scala, split

I have the following lines in a file that I read, I then found the common delimiter which in this case is space, afterwhich I map the column header to the value of each line, then convert to JSON

id        name DOB

1         john doe 2000-01-01

2         jane doe 1990-01-01

there are one or multiple spaces between columns, I need to split each line but keep the names as one unit ("john doe","jane doe"), please note that the delimiter could be also one or more tabs. After converting to  JSON the result wasn't correct due to having three spaces between id and name, and one space between name and DOB

EDIT:
The delimiter is found by finding the most occuring delimiter:

```
val delimitersList = List(",", ";", ":", "\\|", "\\t", "-", "_", "\\+",  "-"," ")
val delimiterMap = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Int]()
for (a <- delimitersList)
  delimiterMap += a ->(a+"+").r.findAllIn(line).length
 val sortedMap = (delimiterMap.toList sortWith ((x, y) => x._2 > y._2)).take(2)
 val firstDelimiter = sortedMap.head._1.toString
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you split by white space or tab and then concatenate 2nd and 3rd items?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know before hand what the delimiter might be, so I read the first line and check for possible delimiters(space,tab,pipe,-,etc.. then I split the remaining lines based on the found delimiter. I have other filess also which need to be run the same way but with possibly different delimiters

Comment: The issue is that some of those files don't contain the same delimiter count separating columns

Comment: Let's say all possible delimiters are `|`, `white space and tab. The regex to split based on any of them would be (\||\s|\t). [A basic example](https://regex101.com/r/U4pNu1/1)

Comment: What do you mean "found the common delimiter"? How is that done? If the data contains multiple spaces, bars `|`, and commas `,`, how is the delimiter determined?

Comment: @ jwvh: please note the question edit

Comment: Your example shows data strings with different numbers of columns/delimiters. What rules does the code use to determine which data elements get grouped into which columns? Why does "jane" and "doe" get combined into the 2nd column?

Comment: The project I'm currently working on converts text files to json, where I parse a bunch of files that may be (SQL, header, map, free text,..etc), some of those files are dirtier than others, those are the ones for which I'm trying to write rules to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Match Following pattern :

> (\d+).*?([a-zA-Z]*? [a-zA-Z]*?) ([0-9]+-[\d]+-[\d]+)

it will match if there is variable space and tabs among columns.But it assume that name is always separated by single space

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Ahw6JB/1/)